# How to route between components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In one of my React project, I've Homepage created as well as Photos and Videos Component. All the data I get is from API. Now in Homepage I get data from JSON as follows (an example)

```
export const data = {
  list : [
    {
      id:'abc123',
      type:'content',
      name:'videos'
    }, 
    {
      id:'pqr124',
      type:'content',
      name:'photos'
    }
  ],
}
```

The HomePage has 'See All' link for Photos and Videos respectively. Now when clicking on See All for Photos routes to Photos Component and url is /content/list/pqr124 and for Videos Component is /content/list/abc123.

So in Home Component

```
const [name, setName] = useState('')
const [newPhotoId, setNewPhotoId] = useState('')
const [newVideoId, setNewVideoId] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
loadData()
})

const loadData = () => {
try {
fetch('data').then(data2 => data2.json()).then(data3 => {
if(data3.list.name == 'photos') {
       setNewPhotoId(data3.list.id)
} if(data3.list.name == 'videos') {
       setNewVideoId(data3.list.id)
}
})
}
}
```

Now two links created

```
See All (for photos) <Link to={{ pathname: `/content/list/${newPhotoId}` /> 

See All (for videos) <Link to={{ pathname: `/content/list/${newVideoId}` />
```

Meanwhile in App.js Component Routing is as

```
<Router>
<Switch>

<Route to="/content/list/:someId" component={PhotosVideos} } />

</Switch>
</Router>
```

Now in order to route seamlessly I created a Middle Component 'PhotosVideos' which gets the respective params and routes accordingly to that component.

PhotosVideos

```
const {someId} = useParams()
const [section, setSection] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
getData()
})

const getData = () => {
try {
fetch(`${someId}/artId=${xyz123}`).then(data => data.json()).then(newData => 
setSection(newData.data.meta_data)
)
}
}
```

Here in getData I recieve data as follows (just an example)
When someId is 'abc123'

```
data = [
meta_data: "videos",
list: {...}
]
```

When someId is 'pqr124'

```
data = [
meta_data: "photos",
list: {...}
]
```

Then I put condition as ``` if(section == 'Photos') {
...Photo Section
}
if (section == 'Videos') {
...Video Section
}

```
When navigating from photos to videos and vice-versa, What could be appropriate solution? I mean What conditions should be applied in App.js in Routing or Do I need to create each seperate components?
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting the type of data from the getdata function and setting the condition, you can create your own video and photo components or you can just render the divs for photos and videos. That is your call. Anything is fine